# When computing Big-Oh, do I need to add up all of the O(1)s?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory

Say I solve a problem that has a time complexity linear to the problem set, but on top of that the program used a few 0(1)s to do some function. Would I then have to add all the O(1)s to the O(n) to get the actual Big-Oh?

Comment: No you don't.. You define complexity in terms of n here it takes linear time so O(n)

Comment: As long as there is only a constant number of O(1)s they will not change an overall O(n) time.

Comment: As long as you don't have n of them.

Comment: @alfC: you probably mean as long as you don't have *more* than (order) n of them.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, well, if you have n of them (n of O(1)) (not necessarily "more")  then you have O(n). Yes, when I say n, I mean order n.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: @alfc: I don't think you get it. n of O(1) is harmless, it doesn't deserve an "as long as".

Answer (score 1):

No, the O(1) are not added together as they consume constant space/time irrespective of the inputs to the algorithm or program.

See [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* add the constant terms if you like, but this is of no use. Indeed, `O(n)` and `O(n+27)` are equivalent (as well as `O(43n-52)`, `O(n/9+1023√n)`, `O(n+log³n)`, `O(√(n²+1))`...).